# How to get value from promise response and assign it to each object property in array in Ionic v3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

attempt 1 : I tried to get data by using this below funtion. Since it is asynchronous, not able to get the value from this function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    let newitems: any = this.items;
    this.restapi.getPendingOrdersCount(this.items[i].store._id, this.user._id).then(data => {
        this.result = data;
        console.log(this.result);
        //able to get the data here
    });

    //Unable to get the data here. 
    newitems[i].pendingCount = this.result;
    console.log("result", this.result);
}
```

attempt 2 : I added extra variable to the above function and did return. Now im able to get this data here but its not value, its a zone value => t {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}

```
let newitems: any = this.items;
for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    var response = this.restService.getPendingOrdersCount(this.items[i].store._id, this.user._id).then(data => {
        this.result = data;
        //console.log(this.result);
        return response;
    });
    //able to get result here but its not value, its a zone value
    newitems[i].pendingCount = this.result;
    console.log("response", response);
}
```

Can anyone help me to correct the above function so that i can reuse promise value.

Comment: The `console.log()` should be inside the `then` block. Like you've said `this.result` is assigned asynchronously. So there is no way to be sure it is assigned the value outside the `then` block.

Comment: why do you return `res` in the second code? (what is res?) you should return data ... then you can always access the result of that promise using `response.then(data => ... data is the data you want ...)` ... or `data = await response;` ... in an `async` function of course

Comment: can you try async/await on the function that is making this call?

Comment: okay, Inside the then is it possible to assign the data to an array like array[i].data = data;

Comment: @JaromandaX I edited the answer, its not res its response.

Comment: how can you return response, if response is the variable that holds the promise? no, as I said, return data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `getPendingOrdersCount` returns a `Promise`, you can simply use the concept of `async/await`. For instance:

```
const response = await this.restapi.getPendingOrdersCount(this.items[i].store._id,this.user._id);
console.log(response); // now it has some values
```

Note that you can only use `await` inside an `async` function. So, if you are calling `getPendingOrdersCount` inside a function like `ngOnInit(){}` you should change it to `async ngOnInit(){}`.

You can read more about `async/await` [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Answer (score 0):

You are using async call to `getPendingOrdersCount` so before `.then` execute the  `console.log("response",response);` will be execute that's why it's not giving data outside `.then`.

You can call `dislayResult` function from `.then` to get data outside like below.

```
this.restapi.getPendingOrdersCount(this.items[i].store._id, this.user._id).then(data => {
  this.result = data;
  console.log(this.result);
  //able to get the data here
  
  displayResult();
});

displayResult() {
   console.log(this.result);
}
```